# What can I do if the Console window is not opening?

Tags: visual-c++

Usually, when I run a program, a black window pops up and displays whatever happens within the program. The default console application has this one:

[image]

A program I'm writing doesn't. There's nothing in the error list, but the output window does have a lot of what looks like errors, though I find it a bit strange that they're there instead of the error list.

I have some questions:

1. Why are errors displayed in the output window, and how can I get them back into the error list?
2. Where do I start looking for what could be stopping the console window from opening?

I've ruled out that there's something wrong with the IDE or my computer, since there were no issues when I ran the basic "hello world" script that pops up after starting a console application project. Unless there's something I've overlooked there?

Comment: Are you certain the project you are having trouble with is a console subsystem application? Could it be a Windows subsystem application instead? What are the lines in output that look like errors? The error list is for compile errors. If your program compiled successfully and you are running it then you may have runtime errors that show in the output.

Comment: *"the output window does have a lot of what looks like errors"*, *"Why are errors displayed in the output window and how can I get them back into the error list"* . Hello, please show us the output window and the errors you say appear. We cannot guess or read your mind :) *"Where do I start looking for what could be stopping the console window from opening?"*. First let's see what the output window shows, then we will need to see the project settings, then the code. There isn't a single answer that solves it all. It takes time and experience to find it, and we need as much info as possible.

Comment: In Visual Studio, the "Error List" window displays heuristics (IntelliSense) errors/warnings predicted during parsing the code on-the-fly, whereas the "Output" window (when chosen to "Show output from: Build") displays the real errors/warnings produced by the compiler during the actual compilation of the code. Thus, in case of discrepancy, the "Output" window is the one to be trusted, not the "Error List" window. The console is not opening probably because you have compilation errors (starting with letter C, e.g., C2440) and/or linkage errors (starting with LNK, e.g., LNK2019). Read those.